# How to find quantity of subsets generated from subsets of a set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

What is the maximum number of subsets that can be formed from $n$ subsets of a fixed set using intersection, join, and complement operations? Answer is $2^{2^n}$, but can you explain why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the fixed set is $A$ with subsets $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$

Then you can find minimal subsets which are of the form $C_k=B_1^c \cap B_2 \cap \cdots \cap B_n^c$ or similar, by intersecting each original subset or its complement.  The $C_k$ are mutually exclusive, their union is $A$ and if there are $m$ distinct minimal subsets then $m \le 2^n$

Any obtainable subset of $A$ is then of the form $D_i=C_1 \cup C_4 \cup \cdots \cup C_{j}$ or similar, by taking the union of a number of $C_k$. The $D_i$ form a sigma-algebra and if there are $s$ distinct obtainable subsets then $s \le 2^m$. So $s \le 2^{2^n}$

Comment: can you please explain second part more detail. Why we intersect to get C subsets? And why their union is A? We don't know how many subsets in A, we just take n from them, and n can be <= |A|

Comment: @IWProgrammer If you have a Venn diagram, the minimal subsets are each of the multiple intersections (so for example  with $n=3$ you partition your Venn diagram into $8$ subsets)